# Using ng-model with select to show data attribute instead of value?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I currently have a simple select list that contains both data attributes and a value:

```
<select ng-model="myList">
    <option value="1" data-name="Test name 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-name="Test name 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-name="Test name 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id="displaySelected">
    {{myList}}
</div>
```

Inside my div (with the ID of `displaySelected`), it is currently displaying the `value` of the selected option.

How can I change this to display the `data-name` attribute instead?

Comment: Is it a static select/options like this?

Comment: @PSL - It's far more complex than I've included above. Although once the select list is created upon load, no elements are ever added to it again.

Comment: How do you build the options though? not via ng-optons?

Comment: @PSL - No, via ng-repeat.

Comment: Then why don't you set value accordingly? basically ng-model will have `.value` property of select which comes from selected option value. Is it something manageable that way? Can you show your code...

Comment: @PSL - Long story, but the value is used in many many other places since it is an ID. I just need to use the `data-name` for display purposes.

Comment: How does the data structure look like that generates these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the complete data structure and other possibilities that are not mentioned in the question. But here is a simple solution for this static list.

```
app.directive('dataselector', function(){
 return{
    restrict:'A',
    require:['ngModel','select'], //Require ng-model and select in order to restrict this to be used with anything else
    link:function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
      //get configured data to be selected, made this configurable in order to be able to use it with any other data attribs
      var dataProp = attrs.dataselector,
          ngModel = ctrl[0]; 

      elm.on('change', handleChange);//Register change listener

      scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
        elm.off('change', handleChange);
      });

      function handleChange(){
        //get the value
        var value = this.value;
        //get the dataset value
        var dataVal = elm[0].querySelector('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').dataset[dataProp];
        //reset ngmodel view value
        ngModel.$setViewValue(dataVal);
        ngModel.$render();
        //set element value so that it selects appropriate item
        elm.val(value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and use it as:

```
 <select ng-model="myList" dataselector="name">
```

**Note**: If you are using a different way(that you are not showing us) to build the select options based on a data structure that has the value populated in the data attribute (like an `ng-repeat`), you could register change event using `ng-change="selectedItem(itemFromRepeat)"` and you can set another property with the data value in the handler and use it.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

}).directive('dataselector', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['ngModel', 'select'],
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      var dataProp = attrs.dataselector;
      elm.on('change', handleChange);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        elm.off('change', handleChange);
      });

      function handleChange() {
        var value = this.value;
        var dataVal = elm[0].querySelector('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').dataset[dataProp];
        ctrl[0].$setViewValue(dataVal);
        ctrl[0].$render();
        elm.val(value);
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="myList" dataselector="name">
    <option value="1" data-name="Test name 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-name="Test name 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-name="Test name 3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <data-select></data-select>
  <div id="displaySelected">
    {{myList}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without using ngRepeat or javascript at all, just by handling in the DOM? Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699857/angularjs-select-tag-getting-attribute-from-option-when-selected/40699908