# AngularJS - select tag - getting attribute from option when selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

So I have a select tag that shows some options and I wish that when an option is selected it takes the `data-something` attribute and pastes its value (of the attribute) in the input element I have. It is only demonstrative, value attribute should be send in the form.

```
<input ng-model="refreshedByExample" type="text">
<select ng-model="example">
    <option value="1" data-something="valueForRefreshedByExample1">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-something="valueForRefreshedByExample2">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-something="valueForRefreshedByExample3">3</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot everyone

Comment: what kind of data structure do you have?

Comment: Hi @alphapilfgrim, its basically that. I'm not using ngRepeat, the values are loaded like that in the DOM. It basically should give 'refreshedByExample' the value of whats inside of the attribute 'data-something' when the option is selected.

Comment: I think you just missing using the same model if I'm understanding correctly. http://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/dONqRv?editors=1010  Unless you still cant get the value of the attribute at all then you should use an attribute type directive.

Comment: I am afraid you are not understanding correctly. The value of "refreshedByExample" should be "valueForRefreshedByExample1" or "valueForRefreshedByExample2" or "valueForRefreshedByExample3", depending of the option selected. In you are example you are not even interacting with the attribute "data-something".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the answer with correct code

```
<input ng-model="refreshedByExample" type="text">
<select ng-model="example" ng-change="refreshByExample=example"> 
    <option ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample1">1</option> 
    <option ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample2">2</option> 
    <option ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample3">3</option> 
</select>
```

See [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

Also consider using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) if your values are contained in a array.

Comment: Ahm... can you demonstrate in code how to change other element's value using ng-value when an option from a select tag is selected? Please. And no, my values are not contained in an array.

Comment: `<select ng-model="example" ng-change="refreshByExample=example">
    <option value="1" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample1">1</option>
    <option value="2" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample2">2</option>
    <option value="3" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample3">3</option>
</select>`

Comment: Sorry, messed up formatting there, also I might have misunderstood your question, but this should do it.
What happens is, you set the value of the `example` variable with the selected option. When the selected value is changed, you set the `refreshByExample` with the same value as `example`.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks! Please, post/edit your answer using the code you just added so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below code, I think it maybe what you're looking for. A custom attribute type directive.

```js
function exampleController($scope) {

}

function extractValue() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      if ($attr.something) {
        $element[0].value = $attr.something;
      }
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController)
  .directive('extractValue', extractValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <input ng-model="example" type="text">
    <select ng-model="example">
      <option value="1" data-something="valueForRefreshedByExample1" extract-value>1</option>
      <option value="2" data-something="valueForRefreshedByExample2" extract-value>2</option>
      <option value="3" data-something="valueForRefreshedByExample3" extract-value>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use `ng-options` in these situations.

```
<select ng-model="example" 
  ng-options="item.value as item.id for item in array">
</select>
```

And the array like

```
$scope.array = [
  {id: 1, value: 'valueForRefreshedByExample1'},
  {id: 2, value: 'valueForRefreshedByExample2'},
  {id: 3, value: 'valueForRefreshedByExample3'}
];
```

EDIT:

The example with Value (if `valueForRefreshedByExample1` isn't a string, use `ngValue`):

```
<input ng-model="example2" type="text">
<select ng-model="example2">
  <option value="valueForRefreshedByExample1">1</option>
  <option value="valueForRefreshedByExample2">2</option>
  <option value="valueForRefreshedByExample3">3</option>
</select>
```

The exemples can be seen here https://plnkr.co/edit/gfYak9zkKsAu0I5eQHx0?p=preview

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I cannot do this. I cannot edit how the code is being generated.

Comment: I mean that the code is given to me as it is, I cannot modify it to now being generated with ng-options, therefore cannot user the array you are proposing.