# AngularJS - Why ng-value overrides value attribute and how to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-ng-value

So, I have the following code:

```
<input ng-model="refreshedByExample" type="text">
<select ng-model="example" ng-change="refreshedByExample = example">
    <option value="1" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample1">1</option>
    <option value="2" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample2">2</option>
    <option value="3" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample3">3</option>
</select>
```

The value of the `value`'s attribute is different than the value in `ng-value`. But, somehow, it is overrides and the `value` attribute gets the same value than `ng-value`. I get something like this:

```
<input ng-model="refreshedByExample" type="text">
<select ng-model="example" ng-change="refreshedByExample = example">
    <option value="valueForRefreshedByExample1" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample1">1</option>
    <option value="valueForRefreshedByExample2" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample2">2</option>
    <option value="valueForRefreshedByExample3" ng-value="valueForRefreshedByExample3">3</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I need to have on the `value` attribute a different value than in `ng-value`.

Any ideas? Thanks everyone.

Comment: You can't have both and the idea of setting them differently doesn't make sense. This is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You really need to explain in full detail what it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Hi. The problem is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699857/angularjs-select-tag-getting-attribute-from-option-when-selected It was solved but new problem found. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Concept is all wrong in the first place. You don't need to store additional data in the dom when you already have that data available in controller

Comment: Unfortunately data is not available in controller due its loaded in the DOM and not by using ng-repeat or ng-options.

Comment: Then you need to explain the dom source generation better. This is very backwards for an angular app where the norm is for the data to determine what gets created in the dom, not the other way around

Comment: Ok, the options are generated by a PHP script and cannot modify by taking it from a service, I was asked to use the code as it is. So my only options is to do this.

Comment: Then I suggest you go back to using the original data attributes and a custom directive. Or pass the data to a javascript variable from php

Comment: Yeah I think it would be best if I just add a "data-something" attribute and assigning to it what I need from the actual value attribute. So, conclusion, you cannot use both, right?

Comment: no...the ng-value directive sets the value so makes no sense using both. Previous answer is just completely wrong

Comment: I need two values here, one to change the DOM and the second one to take to save in database.

Comment: So use a custom directive to parse the data attribute in a change handler. Or set up an api endpoint to get the data set needed

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? I am a bit confused. Thank for your time in advance.

Comment: Directive exposes the select element...then it's a simple matter of getting data attribute from it's selected child and updating controller in a ng-change function within directive. Or fix the app design and use angular to build the dom as it is intended to be used instead of hybrid server/client side templating